# counting bright pixels and summing them. Medical Image C++

Tags: opencv, division, pixel, brightness, counting

Currently, I'm working on a project in medical engineering. I have a big image with several sub-images of the cell, so my first task is to divide the image.

I thought about the next thing:

Convert the image into binary

doing a projection of the brightness pixels into the x-axis so I can see where there are gaps between brightnesses values and then divide the image.

The problem comes when I try to reach the second part. My idea is using a vector as the projection and sum all the brightnesses values all along one column, so the position number 0 of the vector is the sum of all the brightnesses values that are in the first column of the image, the same until I reach the last column, so at the end I have the projection.

This is how I have tried:

```
void calculo(cv::Mat &result,cv::Mat &binary){  //result=the sum,binary the imag.

    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<=binary.rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=binary.cols;j++){
                cv::Scalar intensity= binaria.at<uchar>(j,i);
                result.at<uchar>(i,i)=result.at<uchar>(i,i)+intensity.val[0];
        }
        cv::Scalar intensity2= result.at<uchar>(i,i);
        cout<< "content" "\n"<< intensity2.val[0] << endl;              
    }
}
```

When executing this code, I have a violation error. Another problem is that I cannot create a matrix with one unique row, so...I don't know what could I do.

Any ideas?! Thanks!

---

At the end, it does not work, I need to sum all the pixels in one COLUMN. I did:

```
cv::Mat suma(cv::Mat& matrix){

int i;

cv::Mat output(1,matrix.cols,CV_64F);


for (i=0;i<=matrix.cols;i++){
        output.at<double>(0,i)=norm(matrix.col(i),1);   
    }
    return output;
}
```

but It gave me a mistake:
Assertion failed (0 <= colRange.start && colRange.start <= colRange.end && colRange.end <= m.cols) in Mat, file /home/usuario/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 276

I dont know, any idea would be helpful, anyway many thanks mevatron, you really left me in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the sum of the binary image, you could simply take the L1-norm. Like so:

```
Mat binaryVectorSum(const Mat& binary)
{
    Mat output(1, binary.rows, CV_64F);
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.rows; i++)
    {
        output.at<double>(0, i) = norm(binary.row(i), NORM_L1);
    }

    return output;
}
```

<strike>I'm at work, so I can't test it out, but that should get you close.</strike>

**EDIT :** Got home. Tested it. It works. :) One caveat...this function works if your binary matrix is truly binary (i.e., 0's and 1's). You may need to scale the norm output with the maximum value if the binary matrix is say 0's and 255's.

**EDIT :** If you don't have `using namespace cv;` in your .cpp file, then you'll need to declare the namespace to use `NORM_L1` like this `cv::NORM_L1`.

Have you considered transposing the matrix before you call the function? Like this:

```
sumCols = binaryVectorSum(binary.t());
```

vs.

```
sumRows = binaryVectorSum(binary);
```

**EDIT :** A bug with my code :) 
I changed:

```
Mat output(1, binary.cols, CV_64F);
```

to

```
Mat output(1, binary.rows, CV_64F);
```

My test case was a square matrix, so that bug didn't get found...

Hope that is helpful!

Comment: Ok, tomorrow in the morning I will try it, I will try to upload the results, if I'm not able to do it, talk on monday.Many thanks! i was getting a little bit crazy, and I'm just at the beginning... :)

Comment: Ok, I am trying to do it so, but I have a compiling problem when using the norm function. It says, that NORM_L1 was not declared in this scope, so I could not try it yet. I thought that maybe it is because of a linking library problem, but I think I linked all the libraries, like:
#include <iostream>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

Comment: ok, I realized that I was summing the rows, and that gave me a dimensionality error, as I would like to make the sum of all the brightnesses values along one column, I just change:output.at<double>(0, i) = norm(binary.row(i), NORM_L1);

For output.at<double>(0, i) = norm(binary.col(i), NORM_L1);
And NORM_L1 for 1.

Comment: Ok, I think it is working, I keep you updated if anything changes.

Comment: Ok, the mistake was such a ridiculous mistake, I realized this morning, ok, right now, yes it is definitevely working well.
Thanks