# How to access findNonZero coordinates stored in Mat C++

Tags: c++, opencv, binary, mat

I am a beginner with OpenCV and I have read some tutorials and manuals but I couldn't quite make sense of some things.

Currently, I am trying to crop a binary image into two sections. I want to know which row has the most number of white pixels and then crop out the row and everything above it and then redraw the image with just the data below the row with the most number of white pixels.

What I've done so far is to find the coordinates of the white pixels using findNonZero and then store it into a Mat. The next step is where I get confused. I am unsure of how to access the elements in the Mat and figuring out which row occurs the most in the array.

I have used a test image with my code below. It gave me the pixel locations of [2,0; 1,1; 2,1; 3,1; 0,2; 1,2; 2,2; 3,2; 4,2; 1,3; 2,3; 3,3; 2,4]. Each element has a x and y coordinate of the white pixel. First of all how do I access each element and then only poll the y-coordinate in each element to determine the row that occurs the most? I have tried using the at<>() method but I don't think I've been using it right.

Is this method a good way of doing this or is there a better and/or faster way? I have read a different method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081222/counting-bright-pixels-and-summing-them-medical-image-c/8081502#8081502) using L1-norm but I couldn't make sense of it and would this method be faster than mine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int Number_Of_Elements;
    Mat Grayscale_Image, Binary_Image, NonZero_Locations;

    Grayscale_Image = imread("Test Image 6 (640x480px).png", 0);
    if(!Grayscale_Image.data)
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Binary_Image = Grayscale_Image > 128;

    findNonZero(Binary_Image, NonZero_Locations);
    cout << "Non-Zero Locations = " << NonZero_Locations << endl << endl;

    Number_Of_Elements = NonZero_Locations.total();
    cout << "Total Number Of Array Elements = " << Number_Of_Elements << endl << endl;

    namedWindow("Test Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    moveWindow("Test Image", 100, 100);
    imshow ("Test Image", Binary_Image);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the following to work:

```
Point loc_i = NonZero_Locations.at<Point>(i);
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried what you suggested but I am getting errors. Not sure if I did it wrong or not. by point do you mean Point_ ? Even then I am still getting a lot of errors.

Comment: What I've done is declared loc_i and i as int. Is this wrong?

Comment: `Point` is just a `cv::Point` which is typedef of `cv::Point_<int>`

Comment: Ok, so let's say I want to know the Y-coordinate of the last element in my array. Do I do the following?

Comment: `int y = NonZero_Locations.at<Point>(NonZero_Locations.total()-1).y;`

Comment: I see, I think I mostly get it now apart from the last bit of the code. Can you please tell me what the .y is for?

Also, how do I know whether the code is polling the X or Y coordinate of the pixel? On my example I can test with a test image so I know what you've given me is correct, but just looking at the code I'm not quite sure how to determine that. If I want to poll the X coordinates instead of the Y coordinates, what would I then change in the code?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I just realized the .y means its polling the y-coordinate and replacing it with .x makes it poll the x-coordinate. Thank You @Andrey, you've been a great help